# Connection refused with public key

Tags: linux, ssh, security, root

I need an urgent help please, I have created, as `root`, a file `/home/A/.ssh/authorized_keys` for user `A`. Then I changed the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `PasswordAuthentication no` and `AllowUsers A` and restarted using `systemctl restart sshd`.

My computer entered sleep mode, after pressing the sleep button of the keyboard accidentally, and I wanted to login again using root.

However, I got this msg :

```
publickey gssapi-keyex gssapi-with-mic
```

I cannot login either using `root` or `A` (although in superputty I have imported the private key).

Please help.

Comment: As far as I understand it, you are trying to log on to your local computer. I am not aware of any local login method that uses SSH. Can you edit the question and describe the login process? While you are at it, also provide some details about the operating system you are using.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to connect to the remote machine now, I am not able to connect using putty after my local computer sleeped. OS: CENTOS 7

Comment: I'm guessing that the error message should say `Public key` and not `ublic key`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for this typo

Comment: I really appreciate your help guys.